# Optimal approach for displaying big data tables in a template

Tags: html, django, datatable, bigdata, htmx

Django is used as backend. There is data to display in the template of the client part, that's the question itself. What is the best way to display a table with 5000 rows and 50 columns in a template? which approach would be correct. I'm thinking of implementing it through DataTables, in which case how will the template behave with large data, or are there alternatives and a more suitable pattern for my task? Further in the table I will implement real-time filtering and export to Excel.

I'm thinking of trying htmx, I don't know if it will solve my problem with long loading?

Or caching can speed up page loading?

Please tell me the correct approach, newbie on the fronte
Thank you!

Попробовал DataTAbles, очень долго грузится.

Comment: Yes htmx should be a good fit, check out the "load more" example https://htmx.org/examples/click-to-load/

Comment: Maybe you are already aware, but you don't mention this in your question: DataTables supports ["server-side processing"](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) for those situations when "_reading data from the DOM is simply too slow or unwieldy, particularly when dealing with many thousands or millions of data rows_". Using this approach, your server-side code is responsible for all paging/filtering/sorting logic - and it only needs to send one page of rows to the browser each time. HTMX would not be relevant, in this case.

Comment: @mariodev Yes, good approach. I wonder how filtering through js on the client side will behave? After all, we give the client data as the button is pressed.

Comment: @andrewjames To be honest, I missed this moment, I knew that it could be implemented through the API. Thank you!

Comment: @ars You can have htmx to send GET request when filtering, ordering etc, fetch filtered data in response and display it. All of this should be easily achieved just using htmx. It's the he same way as you would create non-js solution using django.. where with htmx you do same thing using ajax.